# Can I override @SequenceGenerator value at the time of entityManager.persist with some other ID

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

EmployeeID is getting overridden at runtime by sequence nextval although I am setting it explicitly in Service layer. Is there any way to restrict the seq value?

I have Entity class as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="XYZ")
public class Generator implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=AUTO, generator="ID_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="ID_SEQ",sequenceName="ID_SEQ")
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private String EmployeeId;
......
```

I want to set value of EmployeeID at my service layer as:
    setEmployeeId(abc.getEmpID); and then apply the logic -
    if abc.getEmpID is null then EmployeeID should be picked up by SequenceGenerator.

At DaoImpl, I am persisting a list which have all Entity values:
    entityManager.persist -> employeeList;

Expected result is EmployeeID should persist as abc.getEmpID only if it not null else EmployeeID should be sequence nextval.

Comment: If abc.getEmpID is not null, does that mean those entities already exist in database and you want to update those entities?

Comment: @C.Weber: I am trying to use the IDs from another table. If it already exists then no need to create a new ID in my table. If it does not, a new ID should get generated

Comment: Ok, the question is which sequence generator you are using. Are you adding a db function to generate sequence for your tables. Any sequence generator if being used by multiple table should provide unique IDs in the sequence based on the function you have written. Your need to check for sequence existing in other table should be handled by sequence generator and not by your insert/update queries.

Comment: Also is your table using a foreign key ??. Why is there a need to check if the ID already exist in another table. You seem to be taking the relationship between one table to another incorrectly

Comment: @Acewin: No there is not foreign key in the other table. The purpose behind doing this atlast one will be migrating new table to the existing one. So they will check whther the ID exists then update else insert.

Comment: Yes you are correct I am using a singh Sequence for both the tables which will always provide a unque ID always and in the other table also, it is handled by @SequenceGenerator.

Comment: then why do you want to override it service side ??

Comment: I wrote the purpose above, please check. However, I got a way i.e. to use @GenericGenerator and override generate method by passing the object.